# How to fix some columns of table when scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I made a thirteen-column-table, So it cannot be shown in one screen. 
That is, I need to scroll the table horizontally to explore all the data in table.

What I want to do is that the first 4 columns should be fixed even when scroll it to right side.

I found a solution which gives style{position:absolute; left:0} to all the th and tr and not work for me.

Because the number of is not fixed, I add rows with javascript code.

my html code

```
    <div class="div_table">         
      <table>

            <thead>
                 <th>title1</th>
                 <th>title2</th>
                 <th>title3</th>
                 <th>title4</th>
                 <th>title5</th>
                 <th>title6</th>
                 <th>title7</th>
                 <th>title8</th>
                 <th>title9</th>
                 <th>title10</th>
                 <th>title11</th>
                 <th>title12</th>
                 <th>title13</th>
             </thead>



             <tbody id="my-tbody"></tbody>


        </table>
    </div>`
```

my javascript code

```
         var my_tbody = document.getElementById('my-tbody');





                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                          var row = my_tbody.insertRow( my_tbody.rows.length ); 

                          var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
                          col1.innerHTML = data[i].section1;

                          var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
                          col2.innerHTML = data[i].section2;

                          var col3 = row.insertCell(2);
                          col3.innerHTML = data[i].product;

                          var col4 = row.insertCell(3);
                          col4.innerHTML = data[i].product_description;

                          var col5 = row.insertCell(4);
                          col5.innerHTML = data[i].status;

                          var col6 = row.insertCell(5);
                          col6.innerHTML = data[i].rate;

                          var col7 = row.insertCell(6);
                          col7.innerHTML = data[i].start_date;

                          var col8 = row.insertCell(7);
                          col8.innerHTML = data[i].completion_date;

                          var col9 = row.insertCell(8);
                          col9.innerHTML = data[i].proceed_detail;

                          var col10 = row.insertCell(9);
                          col10.innerHTML = data[i].schedule_detail;

                          var col11 = row.insertCell(10);
                          col11.innerHTML = data[i].issues;

                          var col12 = row.insertCell(11);
                          col12.innerHTML = data[i].in_charge;

                          var col13 = row.insertCell(12);
                          col13.innerHTML = data[i].se;
                    }

            }
```

As you can see my table doesn't have  tag.
So, the number of row always changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do it if you make 2 different tables. One with the columns you don't want to move and another with the rest of the columns.

With this html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>First column </td>
        <td>second column </td>
        <td>third column</td>
        <td>fourth ccolumn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First column </td>
        <td>second column </td>
        <td>third column</td>
        <td>fourth ccolumn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First column </td>
        <td>second column </td>
        <td>third column</td>
        <td>fourth ccolumn</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="second-table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdasda </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asda</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asa</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas </td>
        <td>title1 as a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdasda </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asda</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asa</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas </td>
        <td>title1 as a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdasda </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd </td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asda</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asa</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas </td>
        <td>title1 as a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd asdas</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
        <td>title1 as asd asd</td>
        <td>title1 as asd a</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.first-table tr td {
  background-color: pink;
}

.second-table {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

At this moment you have first table above the second one. Then with a bit of jquery, you can calculate the width of first table and add this value as left margin to your second table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firsttablewidth = $('.first-table').outerWidth();
  $('.second-table table').css('margin-left', firsttablewidth - 2 + 'px');
});
```

It will look like this: **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3v650at/2/)**

Comment: I separated the table, but the problem is that the scroll bar is only below the second table.   is there any way to make the scroll bar longer?? ( I want to put the scroll bar under the first table too...

Comment: Follow my example. The scroll is right as you want it. That's why I added the jquery function to add left margin to the scrolled table